# Is Ostara related to Astraea?

Tags: greek

I was watching the finale of American Gods ("[Come to Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Gods_(TV_series)#Episodes)"), which centered on the goddess [Ostara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%92ostre), and I was also just reading this interesting little article on [Astraea](https://earthandstarryheaven.com/2015/04/01/astraea/), and I thought, the two names sound sort of similar...

Ostara is associated with the Spring, and this presents some obvious problems if we relate [Astrea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astraea_(mythology)) to Virgo, and the etymology of Ostara seems to be "dawn" as opposed to "starry", but Ostara is related to the PIE root for "shine" ([h₂ews-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82ews-)), which is close to the PIE root for "star" ([h₂stḗr](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82st%E1%B8%97r)), itself derived from the root for "glow" ([h₂eHs-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82eHs-)).

The concept of return is a major part of Astraea's story, marking the beginning of a new golden age [Astronomica 2.25], which is a rebirth and consistent in that sense with the [vernal](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vernal) domain of Ostara...

Answer (score 3):

Ostara is a goddess of Easter (or, if you accept [Philip Shaw](http://witchesandpagans.com/pagan-culture-blogs/paganistan/easter-is-risen-philip-a-shaw-s-pagan-goddesses-in-the-early-germanic-world.html)'s ideas, the eastern territory or the eastern people). Astraea is a goddess of justice and embodies a sort of hope that someday goodness will return to the world.

So I don't think they're directly related, but I find your idea that they both relate to a Indo-European idea of light intriguing, and I will add a something of my own: maybe both goddesses are related to the idea of hope and light in darkness, or light returning after darkness.

Obviously, both of us are speculating, but I think your final idea that both represent a return of light, or goodness, to the world is probably the connecting factor.